# What's wrong with the following codes?

Tags: jquery, html

I wanted to do a sort of animation where a rectangle would move..However, the code seems to loop only once and the rectangle is static..How do I fix this and what's wrong ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">



            var interval = 10;
var x=0;
var y=0;
var rect = null;
var context ;

function Rectangle(x, y, width, height, borderWidth) {
this.x=x;
this.y=y;
this.width = width;
this.height = height;
this.borderWidth = borderWidth;
}


$(document).ready(function(){


        if (CheckCanvas()){

                var canvas = document.getElementById('Canvas');
                context =canvas.getContext('2d');
                $('#Result').text('Canvas supported...');
                $('#Result').text($('#Result').text()+'Sound supported...'+CheckSound());
                $('#Result').text($('#Result').text()+'Video supported...'+CheckVideo());   
                $('#Result').text($('#Result').text()+'Storage supported...'+Checkstorage());



                DrawRects();
                DrawRect();


            }
        function CheckCanvas(){
                return !!(document.createElement('canvas').getContext);

            }   

        function CheckSound(){


            return !!(document.createElement('sound').canPlayType)

            }

        function CheckVideo(){


            return !!(document.createElement('video').canPlayType)

            }

        function Checkstorage(){


            return !!(window.localStorage)

            }


        function CheckVideo(){


            return !!(document.createElement('video').canPlayType)

            }
        function DrawRect(){
            alert("Draw1");
                clearCanvas();

                updateStageObjects();

                DrawRects();
                setTimeout("DrawRect()", 5);
                alert("Draw3");

            }

        function updateStageObjects() {
            var amplitude = 150;
            var centerX = 240;  
            var nextX = myRectangle.x+ 10;

            myRectangle.x = nextX;  
        }

        function clearCanvas() {
            context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
        }

        function DrawRects(){


                myRectangle = new Rectangle (250,70,100,50, 5);
                    context.rect(myRectangle.x,myRectangle.y,myRectangle.width,myRectangle.height);


                context.fillStyle="#8ED6FF";
                context.fill();
                context.lineWidth=myRectangle.borderWidth;
                context.strokeStyle="black"; 
                context.stroke();


            }



    })

</script>
```

////  Html  /////

```
 <canvas id="Canvas" width="800px" height="800px"> Nor supported</canvas>
```

Edited version

```
            var interval = 10;
var x=0;
var y=0;
var rect = null;
var context ;

function Rectangle(x, y, width, height, borderWidth) {
this.x=x;
this.y=y;
this.width = width;
this.height = height;
this.borderWidth = borderWidth;
}


function DrawRect(){
            alert("Draw1");
                clearCanvas();

                updateStageObjects();

                DrawRects();
                setTimeout(DrawRect(), 5);
                alert("Draw3");

            }

        function updateStageObjects() {
            var amplitude = 150;
            var centerX = 240;  
            var nextX = myRectangle.x+ 10;

            myRectangle.x = nextX;  
        }

        function clearCanvas() {
            context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
        }

        function DrawRects(){


                myRectangle = new Rectangle (250,70,100,50, 5);
                  context.rect(myRectangle.x,myRectangle.y,myRectangle.width,myRectangle.height);


                context.fillStyle="#8ED6FF";
                context.fill();
                context.lineWidth=myRectangle.borderWidth;
                context.strokeStyle="black"; 
                context.stroke();


            }


        function CheckCanvas(){
                return     !!(document.createElement('canvas').getContext);

            }   

        function CheckSound(){


            return !!(document.createElement('sound').canPlayType)

            }

        function CheckVideo(){


            return !!(document.createElement('video').canPlayType)

            }

        function Checkstorage(){


            return !!(window.localStorage)

            }


        function CheckVideo(){


            return !!(document.createElement('video').canPlayType)

            }



$(document).ready(function(){





            if (CheckCanvas()){

                var canvas = document.getElementById('Canvas');
                context =canvas.getContext('2d');
                $('#Result').text('Canvas supported...');
                $('#Result').text($('#Result').text()+'Sound supported...'+CheckSound());
                $('#Result').text($('#Result').text()+'Video supported...'+CheckVideo());   
                $('#Result').text($('#Result').text()+'Storage supported...'+Checkstorage());



                DrawRects();
                DrawRect();


            }
    })
```

Problem still persists..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a sample for you in jsFiddle that works:

http://jsfiddle.net/uZS3g/4/

1. Move the definition part above the normal part
2. Writing DrawRect as an anonymous function will allow for easier callbacks, like this:

   ```
   var DrawRect = function () {
           console.log('draw');
           clearCanvas();

           updateStageObjects();

           DrawRects();
           setTimeout(DrawRect, 5);

   }
   ```

**Edit: I see pimvdb was quicker, you may still play around with the jsfiddle though.**

Answer (score 3):

The function `DrawRect` is defined within the `$(function() {...})`, but you use a timeout with a string. It will be `eval`ed outside that scope, where `DrawRect` is not defined.

You should define the functions outside the `$(function() {...})` instead, or pass a function:

```
setTimeout(DrawRect, 5);
```

Another thing, you call `DrawRects` inside `DrawRect`, which creates a new rectangle with static coordinates. As a result, the rectangle isn't moving.

Thirdly, move the `canvas` variable outside too.

Fourthly, you do not begin a new path, so old rectangles are still painted too. Use `context.beginPath()`.

Fiftly, you have `checkVideo` defined twice.

This fiddle works: http://jsfiddle.net/uZS3g/6/.

Comment: Does anything hit your js error console when testing it?  I threw the code into firebug and was hitting reference errors because the functions weren't defined when you called them (see mine and Arend's answers below)

Comment: Ok, thanks - imho this should be the excepted answer, kudo's to the insightful explanaitions.

Answer (score 0):

Function definitions must come before you attempt to call them.

In this case in your first part

```
...
            DrawRects();
            DrawRect();
....
```

Will call to undefined functions

EDIT:

Moving your if block below all the function definitions should help